# How can we perform reverse stemming in C# using any stemming algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, stemming, porter-stemmer

Is there any algorithm that performs the reverse of any Stemmers Algorithm. That is, given a stem "**require**", how to find all the words with stem "require"?

Always we find variations of the same words e.g. requirement, requirements, requires, required. All have "require" in common. It would be great if we could incorporate a feature to identify all the words with stem "require".

We have tried Stemmers's Algorithm, which gives result like this:

- Exception - except
- Nothing - noth
- prevents - prevent
- clinical - clinic
- disclosing, - disclosing
- collecting, - collecting,

And we have tried the code as below:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strStemPhrase = @"generate generates generated generating generously";

        string result = Regex.Replace(strStemPhrase, @"[\W_]+", " ");

        string[] strStemmedWords = result.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        TestStemmer(new EnglishStemmer(), strStemmedWords);

        Console.ReadKey();
        return;           
    }

    private static void TestStemmer(IStemmer stemmer, params string[] words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stemmer: " + stemmer);

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word + " --> " + stemmer.Stem(word));
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: "And we have tried the code as below:"... but? What´s your question? Does the code work?

Comment: Yes this code is Work...But my que is " how to find all the words with stem "require"?"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *dictionary*. Imagine that you have a collection of English words:

```
  string[] EnglishWords = new string[] {
    "a", 
    "abacus",
     ...
    "generate", 
    "generated",
    "generates",
    "generating",
    "generously",
     ...
    "zymotic",
  };
```

then you can build a dictionary:

```
  // key: stem
  // value: array of the original words  
  Dictionary<string, string[]> reversed = EnglishWords
    .GroupBy(word => Stem(word)) //TODO: put stemming here
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key,
                  chunk => chunk.ToArray(),
                  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Having a `stem` you can easily find original words:

```
  string stem = "require";

  string[] words;

  if (reversed.TryGetValue(stem, out words)) {
    //TODO: put relevant code here 
  }
```